# Fix error MT1008 when running Xamarin.IOS on a simulator using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

Error I am receiving when running Xamarin.ios:

Launch failed. The app 'iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone Xs iOS 12.4'. Error: error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not find file "Link". Please check the logs for more details.

Solutions I tried already:

$ launchctl list|grep UIKitApplication|awk '{print $3}'|xargs launchctl remove (pasted in terminal).

Comment: 1.Delete the app in the device 2. Delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in the project then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucas, I did try the above and I still received the same error.

Comment: Update the IDE to vs 2019 .It supports Xcode 10.0 and iOS 12.x .

Comment: I am using VS 2017 and IOS is 12.4.0.64

Comment: OK let me upgrade to 2019, I will test it and let you know because this will take a while to install.

Comment: Does it work now?